# Edit a row in List<Model> and refresh ListView

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Model as below:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public decimal Sales {get; set;}
}
```

In View Model, I have a property as below:

```
public List<Customers> CustomerList
{
   get => _customerList;

   set 
   {
       if (_customerList != value)
       {
           _customerList == value;
           OnPropertyChanged;
       } 
   }
}
```

In Customer.Xaml, I have a ListView containing a Grid. This ListView has a binding with the property CustomerList mentioned above.

Here I have two issues:

In the same Xaml, I have a popup code which contains Entry controls. When I click Save button, a method is triggered in the ViewModel which has to add an item in the Customers Model and refresh the Grid.

Secondly, if a particular CustomerId already exists in the List, I have to update that Sales figure in the Model.

I tried in the ViewModel Save method as below:

```
Customers customer = new Customers();
customer.Id = "499";
customer.Name = "Sample Customer";
customer.Sale = 2000;

List<Customers> list = new List<Customers>();
list.items.Add(customer);
```

Even though the above values should come from the Entry control, but I hardcoded to test.

When I do this, the item is neither adding in the list nor refreshing the grid. Probably because it is a new instance. Secondly, how to edit a row in the List.

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection` for your `ItemsSource` on the `ListView`, don't create a new one, add and remove entries only to keep the binding intact. Also, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged on your `Customer` object to refresh the values in just that type

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Can you please illustrate how to use ObservableCollection for ItemsSource? Please post as an answer.

Comment: Updated it to an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection` for your `ItemsSource` on the `ListView`, don't create a new one, add and remove entries only to keep the binding intact. Like this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomersList = new ObservableCollection<Customer> { get; set; }

    public void UpdateCustomers(IEnumerable<Customers> newCustomers)
    {
        CustomersList.Clear();

        foreach (var customer in newCustomers)
            CustomersList.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

The `ObservableCollection` replaces the `List` in your case. Think of it as a list with an implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` variant. Whenever an item is added or removed from the collection, the UI will be notified and updated accordingly.

Also, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Customer` object to refresh the values in just that type. I see you already implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModel so I won't go into details here.

Comment: Thanks. In the "Customer" model, I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. But this class only has properties, no methods so it is throwing exception.

Comment: You will need to implement the right event and implement methods as needed. You could also have a look at PropertyChanged.Fody to take this boilerplate code out of your hands.

Comment: Simply by adding ObservableCollection, the grid has started updating. Even when no change done to model. Thanks a ton. But why INotifyPropertyChanged is required in model when ViewModel already implements it?

Comment: No problem! The INotifyPropertyChanged interface needs to be implemented on whatever model you want to update in the UI. When implemented on your view model it will only update properties from you view model, not underlying objects